# Ms Access SQL calculation from multiple rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    InspectionID, Distance, Continuous, structural_grade  
FROM 
    Conditions
WHERE 
    Continuous LIKE ("S%") OR Continuous LIKE ("F%")
ORDER BY 
    InspectionId ASC, Distance ASC
```

Which outputs:

```
262 60.80   S01 3
262 73.10   F01 3
262 82.60   S02 2
262 140.30  F02 2
263 30.80   S01 2
263 46.60   F01 2
380 4.60    S01 3
380 8.50    F01 3
380 9.80    S02 4
380 28.20   F02 4
380 77.70   S03 4
380 97.70   F03 4
```

The ordering is correct. However I'm stuck at what to do next.

Each "S" has a matching "F" with the same numbers Ex S01, F01. I need to access the Distance field of each "F" and minus "S" distance from it.

For examples F01 has a distance of 73.10 and S01 60.80 so the distance between is 12.3. I need to do this for each records and them numbers after the "S" and "F" can go really high yet will always match. ex. S999 - F999

Comment: Does the table include only unique combinations of `InspectionID` and `Continuous`?

Comment: @HansUp I'm not 100% sure what your asking but Continuous "S01" for InspectionID "262" would never repeat. Next One would be "S02" for "262". Note: Continuous can be NULL but then it does not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Mid()` function to extract the digits from your `Continuous` field: `Mid("S01", 2)` yields "01".  Then use those digits when you join the *F* and *S* rows.

With your sample data in Access 2010, the following query gave me this result set:

[image]

```sql
SELECT
    f.InspectionID,
    f.Continuous,
    s.Continuous,
    f.Distance AS F_distance,
    s.Distance AS S_distance,
    f.Distance - s.Distance AS F_minus_S
FROM
    Conditions AS f
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                InspectionID,
                Continuous,
                Distance,
                Mid([Continuous],2) AS digits_only
            FROM Conditions
            WHERE Continuous ALike 'S%'
        ) AS s
    ON
            f.InspectionID = s.InspectionID
        AND Mid(f.[Continuous],2) = s.digits_only
WHERE f.Continuous ALike 'F%'
ORDER BY f.InspectionId ASC, f.Distance ASC;
```

I included several columns which I doubt you want in your final query.  But I think they can be useful during development and testing.

Beware the Access query designer will complain it can't represent that join condition in *Design View*.  If you set up the join in *SQL View*, you can then run the query without Access complaining.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if possible to show the SQL query view and Data view at same time?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand ... a query can't be displayed in *SQL View* and *Datasheet View* simultaneously.

Comment: That's just terrible for developing. I also noticed MS ACCESS loves to reformat SQL into one big blob of text.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.continuous AS 'S Continuous',
a.distance AS 'S Distance',
b.continuous AS 'F Continuous',
b.distance AS 'F Distance',
abs(a.distance - b.distance) AS 'Difference'

FROM Conditions a

INNER JOIN Conditions b
ON a.InspectionID = b.InspectionID
AND substring(a.continuous,2,len(a.continuous)-1) = substring(b.continuous,2,len(b.continuous)-1)

WHERE a.Continuous LIKE 'S%'
AND b.Continuous LIKE 'F%'

ORDER BY a.InspectionId ASC, a.Distance ASC
```

Comment: I get error: Undefined function "substring" in expression